# Deploying an ISO with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, esxi

We have a Jenkins creating an iso and placing it on our ESXI head, the next step is deploying that ISO. I am having a hard time finding documentation on how to do this.

I tried using the vSphere plugin. I am getting an NPE (null pointer exception) when I try to Test the Connection to our vSphere instance. I am not even sure if that is the right plugin to use.

Has anyone done this before? If so could you share what steps you took to get this done?

**Edit:** I have gotten rid of the vSphere plugin as that does not have any option to deploy an iso.